# Ueditor jQuery Text Editor Flips Content

Tags: jquery, textbox, textarea, richtextbox, paragraph

I am trying to use a jQuery rich text editor on my website. I decided to use [Ueditor](http://www.upian.com/upiansource/ueditor/en/). I used the code exactly as shown in the demo to try it out.

Problem is that when I try and type multiple paragraphs into the form, it will flip the order.

---

Example

I type -->

Line 1

Line 2

On submit -->

Line 2

Line 1

---

I do not understand why it is doing this. Can anybody help me? Is there a better jQuery text editor that I should be using?

UPDATE: for the people that run into this problem in the future! I decided to go with [jWysiwyg](http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/) Text editor. I have played around with probably every single one by now and it is the best, in my opinion at least.

It seems that for every one of these rich text editors you need to have a message from the beginning in the box inside p tags for it to work properly in Chrome and safari. Weird wish I knew why?

Comment: did you set insertParagraphs : false ?

Comment: The default val is true, can you change it to false and see if that helped? cuz fromt he definition : insertParagraphs Boolean -
Adds paragraphs between elements according to line breaks. Default: true

Comment: I changed it to false and it still does it. I just tested it on all the browsers and it works just fine in firefox (mac&windows) and internet explorer. But it does the swapping in Chrome and Safari. If you click the little <> html tag to view it as html before submitting it will work properly by putting <p> tags around each line break. I also want it to be true because I want separate paragraphs.

Comment: I wonder if Ueditor doesnt liek the webkit based browsers.These tend to have extra bells and whistles for filtering XSS and other security vulnerabilities. probably something like that is messing things.

do you have a public url? i would like to test in chrome/safari.

Comment: Talking about aternatives, try  http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/ (Tested in Safari 4, Firefox 3.5, Chrome 4.0, Internet Explorer 8.) & http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/(not sure about compatibility check thier website)

Comment: http://www.mindlessloop.com/uEditor/index.php I put two editors on the page one with false and one with true. They both do goofy things in Chrome and Safari. I have a feeling you are right about the webkit browsers. I will look into those other two but I don't want to give up on this editor. Too deep in just to give up. You know?